# How to add an objects to a list in R programming?

Tags: r, list, machine-learning

so i have created a function that creates a graph (A bayesian network) and 2 list of edges. I want to put the graph and two lists of edges into a final list so that I can return it (so the return would be a list always holding three objects). I have read countless stack pages on the append function for lists, but I still get some kind of error that states "x must be an object of class 'bn'." Maybe I am not adding the graphs and lists correctly to my final list? I hope you guys can help me with this. Here is my code below.

Also, if I want to clear a list that possess some objects, would `exampleList <- NULL` do the trick?

```
    startOfMethod(G_0, dataX)
        {
           n = 0
           graphQueue = G_0
           FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED = list()
           FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_NON_REVERSED_CANDIDATES = list()
           graph_lock_andEdges_Array = list()
           While(n < 1000)
           {
             ... code to build a graph G_1

                if(score(G_1,dataX,type="aic") <= score(graphQueue,dataX, type ="aic")){
                  graphQueue = G_1
                  FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED = temp_Lock_Nodes_Array_Reversed
                  FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_NON_REVERSED_CANDIDATES = temp_Lock_Nodes_Array_NonReversed_Candidates
                  print("FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED")
                  print(FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED)

                  print("Break 4")

                }
                n = n + 1 
          }
          graph_lock_andEdges_Array = c(graph_lock_andEdges_Array, list(graphQueue))
          graph_lock_andEdges_Array = c(graph_lock_andEdges_Array, list(FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED))
          graph_lock_andEdges_Array = c(graph_lock_andEdges_Array, list(FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_NON_REVERSED_CANDIDATES))
          return(graph_lock_andEdges_Array)
    }
```

Comment: Put an object into a specific position in the list `graph_lock_andEdges_Array <- list(graphQueue, FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED, FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_NON_REVERSED_CANDIDATES)`

Comment: @nya For some reason its the first element in the list "graphQueue" that when i try to print with `print(graph_lock_andEdges_Array[1])` it prints `null`

Comment: the graph is in a form of a matrix, im not sure if that information would help at all?

Comment: Use `print(graph_lock_andEdges_Array[[1]])`. Square brackets are doubled in lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the returned list should contain three objects, we can directly put them into the results list.

```
graph_lock_andEdges_Array <- list(graphQueue, FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED, FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_NON_REVERSED_CANDIDATES)
```

To access individual list elements, use doubled square brackets. I'll demonstrate on some example data.

```
graphQueue <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED <- list(matrix(5:8, ncol=2))
FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_NON_REVERSED_CANDIDATES <- list(matrix(9:12, ncol=2))
graph_lock_andEdges_Array <- list(graphQueue, FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_REVERSED, FINAL_LOCKED_NODES_ARRAY_NON_REVERSED_CANDIDATES)

# display the first list element
print(graph_lock_andEdges_Array[[1]])

# display the first cell in the second row
print(graph_lock_andEdges_Array[[1]][2,1])
```

Note that the second and third elements are lists in lists. To display the first cell in the second row in the second list element, we use:

```
print(graph_lock_andEdges_Array[[2]][[1]][2,1])
```

To answer the second question, yes `<- NULL` will clear the content of the object.

```
str(graph_lock_andEdges_Array)
List of 3
 $ : int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : int [1:2, 1:2] 5 6 7 8
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : int [1:2, 1:2] 9 10 11 12
graph_lock_andEdges_Array <- NULL
str(graph_lock_andEdges_Array)
 NULL
```

Comment: thanks so much! it ended working. Just those small syntax errors :/.